# Почему A<Derived>::S* не приводится к A<Base>::S*?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>


template<typename T>
class A {
    
public:
    struct S {};

    S* ptr = nullptr;
    T* ptr_t = nullptr;

    A(T* ptr_t) : ptr_t(ptr_t){}

    template<typename U>
    A(A<U>& other) : ptr(other.ptr), ptr_t(other.ptr_t){}
};


struct Base {};

struct Derived : Base {};


int main(){
    A<Derived> b(new Derived());
    A<Base> d = b;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69908776/5767249

Comment: Надо смотреть с другого конца: почему `Derived *` приводится к `Base *`? Потому что в потомке есть подобъект класса-родителя, на который этот новый указатель может указывать. А в вашем случае содержимое `A<Derived>::S` и `A<Base>::S` может быть совершенно разным.